# Staubli TX2 with CS9 Controller

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a couple of Staubli TX2's, each with the CS9 Controller. Is it possible to have these working with ROS? I see that in Wiki, there is a VAL3 driver (https://github.com/ros-industrial/staubli_experimental/tree/kinetic-devel/staubli_val3_driver).

Has anyone controlled a TX2 with ROS?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299054/staubli-tx2-with-cs9-controller/) by [JamTom](https://answers.ros.org/users/36734/jamtom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `staubli_val3_driver` on the `staubli_experimental` repository is **not** compatible with CS9, but only due to the change from text interfaces to HTML-based that CS9 brings. Disabling the `screenUpdate` task brings it back into compatibility for the most part.

We are currently working on some improvements on the `staubli_val3_driver`, among them, CS9 compatibility, and -of course- would like to contribute it back to the repo once it's ready.

---

Originally posted by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) with karma: 180 on 2019-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-05**:
I've made this the accepted answer as, as of right now (2019-05-05), `staubli_val3_driver` is not compatible with CS9 controllers.

If/when @gonzalocasas contributs his changes this might change. I assume he'll update this answer if/when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I'll post an answer in the context of `staubli_val3_driver`, other readers may post different solutions)

The short answer is: we don't know. The package you found (`staubli_val3_driver`) has only been used with CS8 controllers. I have not received any reports from users with CS9 controllers.

It's been a while since I've worked with Staubli robots, so I don't know how bw-compatible the control software on a CS9 is. If you'd be willing to try that would be very much appreciated.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1